# Error trying to build Robot_localization from git

Tags: ros, navigation, catkin-install, robot-localization, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to install the package robot_localizaton from i am using these commands to download it from github.

```
cd ~/ros_catkin_ws/src
git clone -b kinetic-devel https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization.git
cd ~/ros_catkin_ws
catkin_make
```

then i am running into the error:
>-- +++ processing catkin package: 'tf2_bullet'

> -- ==> add_subdirectory(geometry2/bullet)
> -- Checking for module 'bullet'                                                                                                                                                                                                              >--   No package 'bullet' found                                                                                                                                                                                                               >CMake Error at
> /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:415
> (message):
> A required package was not found
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:588
> (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
> geometry2/bullet/CMakeLists.txt:7
> (pkg_check_modules)
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
> See also
> "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".                                                                                                                                                                          > See also
> "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
> Invoking "cmake" failed

even though I have tf2_bullet installed in my Geometry2 package. is the problem that the cmake is looking for 'bullet' verses 'tf2_bullet'?

Edit: I am following the procedure laid out by @gvdhoorn

im getting stuck on the error

> pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws $
> rosdep install --from-paths src
> --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic                                                                                                                                            ERROR: the following packages/stacks
> could not have their rosdep keys
> resolved
> to system dependencies:
> orocos_kinematics_dynamics: No
> definition of [python_orocos_kdl] for
> OS version [stretch]

i have cloned this git https://github.com/orocos/orocos_kinematics_dynamics in the src file but rosdep install is still not recognizing it. any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274500/error-trying-to-build-robot_localization-from-git/) by [pacifickid9](https://answers.ros.org/users/32335/pacifickid9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-31**:
Could I *please* ask you to *always* include information on the platform (and OS) that you're trying to build things for? Especially ARM platforms are limited in what does and doesn't work, and not mentioning this can lead to long debugging/diagnostic sessions with no apparent progress, because ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-31**:
.. the people involved have different assumptions about key aspects like this.

**Comment by [pacifickid9](https://answers.ros.org/users/32335/pacifickid9/) on 2017-10-31**:
Sorry still new at this. I am trying to install in on a raspberry pi 3 model B, and the OS is raspbian jessie. Sorry what are ARM platforms?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-31**:
ARM is the name of the mfg (well, technically, designer) of the CPU that runs your RPi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`git clone`-ing a package into a workspace is in almost all cases not enough to get it to build.

See #q252478 for the proper procedure.

---

Edit:

> im getting stuck on the error

> ```
> pi@raspberrypi:~/ros_catkin_ws $ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic
> ```

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
orocos_kinematics_dynamics: No definition of [python_orocos_kdl] for OS version [stretch]
```

> i have cloned this git https://github.com/orocos/orocos_kinematics_dynamics in the src file but rosdep install is still not recognizing it. any suggestions?

I just tried this myself and with just `orocos_kinematics_dynamics` and `robot_localization` in the source space of a workspace I get no complaints from `rosdep` (but that is on Ubuntu-Xenial+ROS-Kinetic on `amd64`).

The error essentially tells you that `orocos_kinematics_dynamics` states a dependency on `python_orocos_kdl`, but `rosdep` can't find that package. That would be strange, as it is part of the same repository. Can you make sure that you've cloned the `orocos_kinematics_dynamics` repository correctly (ie: does it show up in  `tree -d -L 2 $HOME/ros_catkin_ws/src`)?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1